# Will Ubuntu Phone OS run Ubuntu Applications?

Tags: phone, ubuntu-phone

Now that the Ubuntu Phone OS is coming soon, I'm just wondering if it will be able to run Ubuntu Applications like LibreOffice or something else that is not exactly made for the phone but is made for the Ubuntu Desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as they are compiled for ARM processors, then I believe yes. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM